# Create "function chain" (for configuration class)

Tags: c++

I have a class which contains the configuration for a different class I have. I want to make something similar to this:

```
Configuraion config;
config = config.configData1(3)
        .configData2(2)
        .configData3(4);
```

I have seen that in Java already and I wanted to know whether and how that is possible in C++.

My configuration class looks similar to this:

```
class Configuration
{
public:
    Configuration()
    {
        loc_configData1 = 0;
        loc_configData2 = 0;
        loc_configData3 = 0;
    }

    const Configuration& configData1(int n)
    {
        loc_configData1 = n;
        return *this;
    }

    const Configuration& configData2(int n = 1)
    {
        loc_configData2 = n;
        return *this;
    }

    const Configuration& configData3(int n = 6)
    {
        loc_configData3 = n;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int loc_configData1;
    int loc_configData2;
    int loc_configData3;
}
```

Comment: If you did not return `const` then this would be possible.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked!

Comment: I personally strongly dislike it, but [this](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) is probably what you want